# Drools - When to use multiple kie sessions?

Tags: drools

I'm new to drools and I'm trying to understand when multiple kieSessions should be used in a drools project.
I did not manage to find much on this topic in the documentation other than:

> "You could decide to create multiple sessions ... if you need multiple
> sessions for ***scalability reasons***."

I'm not quite sure what scalability refers to here. Is it about the number of facts inserted in the kie session? or is it about the number of rules? Or is it simply about running the same project but for different clients by assigning to each client 1 kie Session?

Comment: It's more about the volume of calls to the rules than the number of facts being inserted. If you call your rules on average once every 15 minutes, that's quite different than calling 15 times per second. It's the same principle (in general terms) as to why you share jdbc connections when querying a database -- when volume is low, whether you're doing connection pooling is really irrelevant; but when you have significant throughput, it becomes critical to the performance of your application.

Answer (score 0):

> trying to understand when multiple kieSessions should be used in a drools project

Stateful sessions require separate session per client for repeated requests (stateful means the session keeps the data); stateless sessions do not.